# Undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass Ruby on Rails essential training

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

*the error i get is this,it says NoMethodError in Pages#delete*

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #6):
4
5
6
7
8
9

```
<h2>Delete Page</h2>

<%= form_for(:page, :url =>{:action => 'destroy', :id => @page.id}) do |f| %>

   <p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this page ?</p>
```

*My delete.html.erb from pages*

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index'}, :class =>'back-link') %>

<div class="pages delete">
    <h2>Delete Page</h2>

    <%= form_for(:page, :url =>{:action => 'destroy', :id => @page.id}) do |f| %>

       <p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this page ?</p>

       <p class="reference-name"><%= @page.name %></p>

       <div class="form-buttons">
          <%= submit_tag("Delete Page") %>
       </div>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

*My pages controller*

```
  class PagesController < ApplicationController

   layout false

  def index
    @pages = Page.sorted
  end

  def show
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @page = Page.new({:name => "Default"})
  end

  def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params)
    if @page.save
      flash[:notice] = "Page created successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def edit
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    if @page.update_attributes(page_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Page updated successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @page.id)
    else
      render('edit')
    end

  def delete
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    page = Page.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Page destroyed successfully."
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end

  private 

     def page_params
      params.require(:page).permit(:subject_id, :name, :permalink, :position, :visible)
     end
  end


end
```

*Any help will be appreciated ,thank you*

Comment: It appears you are accessing the delete page of a page object that does not exist. Are you sure the id in the /pages/delete/:id is valid?

Comment: Can you show us your routes.rb?

Comment: here is my route.rb Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'demo#index'

  #get 'demo/index'
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post] end

Answer (score 0):

Vitaly Stanchits is right. When your controller action:

```
def delete
  @page = Page.find(params[:id])
end
```

executes – it's clearly setting `@page` to `nil`, which means it can't find a page with the given id.

You could run `rake routes` for us just to confirm that `/pages/delete/:id` is indeed the expected route for your delete view, and verify that you're visiting the proper path based on the result eg. `/pages/delete/25`

If you're certain that `@page = Page.find(25)` in your delete action should be returning a valid db record, try dropping a `debugger` statement in your delete action to ensure your hitting the right part of your controller, and to check the value of `params[:id]`.

Comment: i run rake routes this is what i got Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
  root GET      /                                      demo#index
       GET|POST /:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format) :controller#:action

Comment: That universal route should catch the `/pages/delete/25` url... and pass 25 as the params[:id]. Can you verify the actual url you are visiting when you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely with your *routes* (rather than your controller).

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :pages do
   get :delete #-> url.com/pages/:id/delete
end
```

This will allow you to call the `delete` path for your `@page`:

```
#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def delete
      @page = Page.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/pages/delete.html.erb
<%= form_for @page, method: :destroy do |f| %>
   <p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this page ?</p>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

It must be noted that this is out of the scope of "resourceful" controller actions, as described here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Whenever you create your *routes* in Rails, it's based about the "resourceful" principle (which I'll explain in a second):

[image]

The above is created whenever you call `resources :x` in your `config/routes.rb` file. This gives you a set of routes with which you can perform *most* of your actions on your objects:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Page", @page, method: :destroy, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

The above points to the `destroy` action (which is what your form points to), allowing you to safely delete the object in question.

--

The reason this is important is that I see many people - learning Rails - who populate their controllers with out-of-scope actions. For example:

```
#app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
   def home
   end

   def contact
   end
end
```

There is *nothing* wrong with this, except that it goes against the convention of keeping your application [*object orientated*](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/object-oriented-programming). In OOP (which Ruby is built on top of), the *object* takes precedent.

The above controller puts the [*flow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming) first; bad for Rails. The way it *should* be done is to call the `@static_page` through the *show* action.

Thus, for your situation, you have to remember that if you want to call a `delete` action, you need to make sure it's in the scope of your application...

You *could* do the following for example:

```
#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @pages = Page.all
   end
end

#app/views/pages/index.html.erb
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
    <%= link_to "Delete Page", page, method: :destroy, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```